# What is it called when JS is used to show only a certain part of a png?

Tags: javascript, css, icons, png, css-sprites

Let's say you have a `png` and it contains all of the `icons` that are to be used on one page, what is the process of using JS to select and display on a certain `icon` in that image? I've always seen it being done, but it seems to evade me what it is, and how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's done with CSS, not JavaScript, and it's called sprites.

http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/

Comment: Many websites do check for certain conditions in js and then depending on them change the css through js.
So it can be done through js as well :)

Comment: Fair enough.  However, it is simple and easy to do with no JS at all.  There may be some helper libraries out there, but if you can leave JS out of this, you should because your page will be faster and cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

You would use CSS and if you want it to be a really painless experience use this website below.

http://www.spritebox.net/

It will take care of generating the picture and also making generating the CSS you will need to output the icons.

Answer (score 0):

Sprites, but you would probably use CSS rather than Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are referring to [sprite image](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp).  js or css can be used to select images.